# Error in Genetic Algorithm (Octave)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, compiler-errors, octave, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm in octave.

My code is http://codepad.org/NeaWqa90

I get the following error:

```
>> run("a.m")
parse error near line 31 of file /home/teron/a.m

  nested functions not implemented in this context

>>> function [x,y]=crossover(x,y)
           ^
error: called from 'run' in file /usr/share/octave/4.0.0/m/miscellaneous/run.m near line 84, column 5
>>
```

I do not know how to resolve this error

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code here so that people don't have to go to a different site just to get the necessary context (please note I don't mean post your whole program, just the part that is relevant to the error). Also, what have you done to try to resolve the error? You say you can't, but didn't say why. Have you done any debugging or other problem solving?

Comment: Also, I'm flagging this for now since it falls under the category of a debugging request without sufficient detail as to what is supposed to be going on compared to what you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is rather informative, namely the part about "nested functions". For instance, the following gives us the same error.

```
function fun1
    function fun2
    end
end
```

Save this into a text file (eg. `temp.m`), and run it.

```
octave:2> run('temp.m')
parse error near line 3 of file /home/me/temp.m

  nested functions not implemented in this context

>>>     function fun2
               ^
error: called from 'run' in file /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/miscellaneous/run.m near line 80, column 5
```

I suspect you're missing an `end` around line 13, but well-formatted code would go a long way.